# gps conversion of Time object

Tags: astropy

I am trying to  figure out why when a time object is converted to GPS time, it becomes an array rather than remaining as a Time object. Example:

```
from astropy.time import Time

times = Time([56701, 56702], format="mjd", scale="tdb")
times.gps

Out: array([  1.07628475e+09,   1.07637115e+09])
```

While conversion to other times gives:

```
times.utc
Out: <Time object: scale='utc' format='mjd' value=[ 56700.9992224  56701.9992224]>
```

Which I believe is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPS is defined in astropy as a time *format* not a *scale*. There is some ambiguity here as discussed in [#1879](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/1879). In the end we decided to keep GPS as just a format, in which case the output of `times.gps` as a numpy array is the expected correct behavior.

There is a pull request [#2091](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/2091) which clarifies the situation with GPS time.